# Zoom part of html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, zooming

I need to something like this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Magnifying-Glass-Image-Zoom-Plugin-magnify-js/ but instead of a picture should be a html page, and zooming should be part of html elements, is it really?

Comment: Yes. The same mechanism. But instead using a big image, you basically have to "clone" the whole html content and put it in your magnifying glass. Then apply css scaling for it (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Jquery plugin "Anything Zoomer". please go through the following link.

https://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/double.php